# Would 0.1.0.1/16 be a valid public ip address?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

I have a question regarding the validity of the IP address 0.1.0.1/16. After consulting the reserved IP list provided by IANA, I noticed that only the ranges 0.0.0.0/8 and 0.0.0.0/32 are listed as reserved. This leads me to wonder if addresses outside of this range, such as 0.1.0.1/16, can theoretically be used. Or Am I missing something?

Comment: Network `0.0.0.0/8` is from address `0.0.0.0` to address `0.255.255.255` and it include `0.1.0.0/16`

Comment: ↑ in other words, no, you can't use anything beginning with 0.

Comment: @RomeoNinov oh yes that's right I completly forgot. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the IP address 0.1.0.0/16

... it isn't an "*IP address*" (singular), but rather a range of addresses that fall into the subnet with a 16-bit mask. This is [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

```
0.1.0.0/16 is:

  255    .   255    .     0    .     0
11111111 . 11111111 . 00000000 . 00000000 - subnet mask, i.e: /16, or 16x 1's

    0    .     1    .     ?    .     ?
00000000 . 00000001 . ???????? . ???????? - network address
                      xxxxxxxx . xxxxxxxx - host address
```

> This leads me to wonder if addresses outside of this range, such as 0.1.0.0/16, can theoretically be used

It's not outside this range - `0.1.0.0/16` (i.e: `0.1.0.0` to `0.1.255.255`) is wholly covered by `0.0.0.0/8` (i.e: `0.0.0.0` to `0.255.255.255`).

```
0.0.0.0/8 is:

  255    .     0    .     0    .     0
11111111 . 00000000 . 00000000 . 00000000 - subnet mask, i.e: /8, or 8x 1's

    0    .     ?    .     ?    .     ?
00000000 . ???????? . ???????? . ???????? - network address
           xxxxxxxx . xxxxxxxx . xxxxxxxx - host address
```

The `0.0.0.0/8` range is listed in the [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml), you can see that all of the addresses in this range may be a "*Source*", but may not be a "*Destination*", are not "*Forwardable*", and are not "*Globally Reachable*" - along with being "*Reserved-by-Protocol*".

As indicated by the registry, [RFC791 Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791.html#section-3.2) (and other RFCs) is a good place to start if you'd like to read into what's going on here.

> A value of zero in the network field means this network.  This is
> only used in certain ICMP messages.  The extended addressing mode
> is undefined.  Both of these features are reserved for future use.

Fundamentally, no - you can't use anything starting with `0.*`